# Best way to access my computer/network from anywhere while having public IP. ISP uses NAT

Tags: router, vpn, remote-desktop, nat

I'd like to be able to access my home computer/devices from anywhere with remote desktop on my tablet, I tried using a free DDNS to see if that would work but I realized my router is behind NAT so the IP that the public sees is not my real IP which means... Trying to connect through the domain name the DDNS gave me is not possible, or at least that's the conclusion I came to by trying for hours.

I went on and purchased a subscription to CyberGhost VPN but then I didn't see anything that indicates I could achieve what I wanted with that so I just went for the refund (yeah, not the smartest of cookies haha)

I know this is possible with a static IP but I'm not sure if I can do it without it.
Is this possible and if yes? What are the steps and services I will need?

Comment: You can use SoftEther VPN (Open Source free and Cross Platform) and use the provided VPN Azure feature of the server to access your system behind NAT. https://www.softether.org/

Answer (score 2):

A static or dynamic ip-address doesn't matter. The problem is NAT.
This prevents connections from the Internet from reaching your router.
Essentially a NAT makes the connection one-way. From your local LAN you can connected to the rest of the world (and receive return-traffic), but connections in the other direction (initiated from the internet to your router) don't work.

What you need is a product like TeamViewer of AnyDesk or similar. You install that on your computer at home and you install the corresponding client on your tablet.

Taking TeamViewer as example (competing products do basically the same):
The TeamViewer software on your computer at home establishes a connection to the TeamViewer servers. The client on your tablet does the same thing. The TeamViewer servers then link those 2 together and forward the connection from the tablet to the computer at home.
By using the TeamViewer servers as intermediary the limitations of NAT are worked around.

The TeamViewer client on the tablet acts as an alternative to Remote Desktop. You can use it to take over the computer at home and even transfer files to and from the computer

Comment: I already use Anydesk and I don't find it that pleasant, especially transmitting hotkeys like "ctrl + Shift + Alt + X" doesn't work and I'm big on using shortcuts, that's why I want to use Remote Desktop. So the only solution for Remote Desktop is to get rid of NAT? No other way?

Comment: It’s specifically a CGNAT that’s the problem, not just NAT, as you would be behind a NAT regardless once you add consumer (or even business) networking equipment into the mix

Comment: @Ramhound NAT or CGNAT doesn't matter. Having no control over the NAT is the actual problem. Anyway I didn't want to make it too complicated.